# Traffic Camera IR image question

Tags: camera, infrared, image-analysis

Recently me and my daughter were photographed by a Traffic IR camera for not wearing the seat belt.While my image when viewed carefully in digital form the belt could be seen.The black belt had turned white and I was wearing a black T shirt which had also turned white.
The problem was with my daughters image where the belt was totaly invisible she was also wearing a black TSHIRT which is made of Polyester, viscose and elastane material with "EVERLAST" written in Flourosenct colour.The amazing thing was that the words EVERLAST appeared on my daughters neck in the image.
My question is that is it possible to send the images to a lab where they can check them out using different processes or lights if so where can I send them to be analysed or is there a software which I can download and analyse.
Look forward to the advise and help
Thanks
Regards
Diana

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this question is on-topic for this stack, but I'd like to let other people chime in. If you're seeking product or service recommendations, that's definitely off-topic here, because the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets. If you're seeking an opinion from analysis professionals to challenge the ticket, then that's a question better for an attorney.

Comment: @scottbb I think the question is entirely off topic. I'd recommend one or more legal SEs. The connection to photography seems to be an automatic police camera of unknown manufacture or abilities. The OP makes several assumptions upon which the questions are based. And the questions are legal, legal strategy, and ways to analyze a photo to reinterpret its meaning.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography within the context of the community description. It is not related to how to produce artistic, documentary, or historical photographs. Questions regarding legal issues when *producing* photographs can be on topic here, but this is not remotely about a photo created with the photo as the end goal, which is what this community is about.

Comment: I don't really understand. You want the photo to be "analysed". What do you mean exactly? What kind of outcome are you expecting from this analysis? If you simply want to dispute the traffic violation, then go through the normal procedure for that. I'm sure it has been detailed to you in whatever notification(s) you've received.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments and discussion I am only trying to find out if there is an organisation or a company which can analyse the photos taken by the traffic cam.While the community may have been set up for a different purpose I am only looking for help here since you all are discussing photography.I am only seeking if there is a way to see a photograph ina different light which may light up the invisible objetcts in this case a seat belt.

Comment: If your seatbelt can be seen, who is the object of the violation? How old is your daughter? In UK a driver is only responsible for children under 14. They can't be responsible for adults because if a passenger undoes the belt while on the move, the driver may not be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment in the stete of Queensland in Australia the legisltion makes the driver responsible for all the passengers above the age of 16.The driver is fined 4 demerit points and 1164 Australian dollars.When I recieved the fine notice the from the B/W  image on the paper both our seatbelts were not visible.I then downloaded the images from departments website and I could see my seatbelt clearly but my daugthers seatbelt in completely invisible except it is only slightly visible at certain points in the begning.

Comment: The reason I even reached this community is because I was searching online for answers and I came accross this artcle. I am not sure how to contact Michael C as I think he may have the answer.https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100430/how-do-different-colours-look-in-infrared-light

Comment: Again, I don't really understand what you want from the analysis. If you can see the seatbelt in the downloaded image, then presumably another human will be able to see the seatbelt too. Make it easy for yourself and everyone else - go through the normal procedure to appeal. When another human gets involved, everything should be sorted, I would assume. I guess this happens all the time. Their automated system has some level of errors, which get rectified by manual intervention on appeal.

Comment: I would: Find someone in authority who is able to reverse the decision - dealing with people below that level is pointless as they cannot help you. || Show them the photo that shows your seatbelt - AND the one that doesn't. || Then tell them that your daughter was also wearling her belt. || THEN show them the photo that has the text in the wrong place AND a photo of the shirt (and maybe of her wearing it. || Siggest that the camera system appears to be malfunctioning.  ...

Comment: ... || If they do not cancel the proceedings at that point ask them who you should approach about the faulty camera in your daughters case and the substandard image in your case.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments once again.I have been able to succesfully overturn my fine.I am only looking for a company which can forensically test the images and bring out objects which may have got hidden due to IR Camera anomalities. If I can prove this then I can approach the Department of Main Roads and notify them about this so they do not fine other people.If you know of such a facility which can forensically examine an image please let me know.